# Get checked checkbox based on Database

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cb"  /></td>
```

how i get this checkbox checked based on my database content
on my database field the contents is 1 and 0

if 1 checkbox will checked
and if 0 checkbox unchecked

How i do that

in my view i have 5 checkbox......

```
  1  2  3  4  5
1.[] [] [] [] []
2.[] [] [] [] []
3.[] [] [] [] []
4.[] [] [] [] []
```

my field status on database........

```
| Status    |
| 1,2,3     |
| 1,2,3,4,5 |
| 2,3,4     |
| 1,2,5     |
```

**Updatee**

how i get checked checkbox

```
    <?php $j=1; foreach ($dudu as $row2 ): ?>

    <td><input type="checkbox" name="popok[]"
  <?php if(strrpos($row->menu_allowed,''.$j.'')!==FALSE){echo 'checked';$j++;}/></td>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

if the data 1,2,3,4 it will check

```
1    2   3   4
[v] [v] [v] [v]
```

but if the data not sequential like 1,3,4 it only check the first box

```
1    3  4
[v] [] []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller get the chek box value

```
<?php
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {

        $check_status = $this->test_model->get_checkbox_status();
        $data['check_status'] = $check_status;

        $this->load->view('testview', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

then in your view

```
<td><input <?php if($check_status==1){"checked='checked'";}?> type="checkbox" name="cb"  /></td>
```

**UPDATE**

use `strrpos`

```
<?php if(strrpos($check_status,'1')!==false){"checked='checked'";}?>
```

this will check `1`

another method using a for loop

```
<?php  for($i=1;$<6;$i++) { >?

<td><input <?php if(strrpos($check_status,$i)!==false){"checked='checked'";}?> type="checkbox" name="cb"  /></td>

<?php } ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Comment: okay i understand you answer, but can i ask you more?......i have 5 checkbox on my view and on my status_field have more than 1 number.....I've complete my question above, in order to more clearly

Comment: can you give me a little help, i use your logic and i try to make it dynamic......but i have some problem, the checkbox not checked for some condition.....i update my question....

Comment: you increment the value $j inside the if condition ,  if your if condition fails , the value $J will not get incremented . so move the variable out side the if condition .

Comment: yeah you're right...i dont realize that and i took an hour to know that....thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

when field in you database is one print this instead of you existing code.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked="checked"  />​
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you fetch value in the following variable

```
var cbValue = getValueFromDB();
```

Using JQuery:

```
if (cbValue == 1 ){
    $('input[name="cb"]).attr(this.checked);
}
if (cbValue == 0){{
    $('input[name="cb"]).removeAttr("checked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$check_val = //Collect from db
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" <?php if($check_val=='1') echo checked;?>>
<input type="checkbox" name="check2" <?php if($check_val=='0') echo checked;?>>
```

may you can get from this

Comment: yeah i use this but if i change $check_val=='2' on checkbox 2 the checkbox just checked on row 3 because its start with 2, and not checked on row 1,2,4

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also use

```
    1    2    3    4    5
 1 [00] [01] [02] [03] [04]
 2 [10] [11] [12] [13] [14]
 3 [20] [21] [22] [23] [24]
 4 [30] [31] [32] [33] [34]
```

as id's individually and then store it in database